# Django builtin url 'logout' reverse URL is returning a relative path

Tags: django, django-authentication

Been searching but can't find this specific issue.  I created a separate app for my user authentication (name: user) and included the URLS using django.contrib.auth.urls.  Login works.  Logout fails.

When using the named view `{% url 'login' %}` the path is absolute, and works fine (i.e. /user/login).
When using the named view `{% url 'logout' %}` in the same template, it gets a relative path to my displayed app. (i.e. user/login)

Django Directory:

```
- djangoProject
  - djangoProject
  - app1
  - user
```

Django app settings (djangoProject/settings.py):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'user',
    'app1',
]
```

Django app URLS (djangoProject/urls.py)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('app1/', include('app1.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('user/', include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
    path('user/', include("user.urls")) // in case I add custom pages
]
```

User App URLS (user/urls.py - nothing added, as using from django.contrib.auth.urls):

```
urlpatterns = [

]
```

User App Views (user/views.py - nothing added.  using built in django.contrib.auth):

Now, in app1/templates/base.html, I use the following:

`{% url 'login' %}` - which generates the URL - `http://host/user/login/`

`{% url 'logout' %}` - which generates the URL - `http://host/app1/user/logout`

If I manually enter the URL `http://host/user/logout` I get logged out and redirected correctly.

Any thoughts?  Thanks so much!

Comment: Perhaps try creating a project level templates directory, set your templates DIR setting in settings.py to 'DIRS': [str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('templates'))] and put your base.html in there. Or namespace your app level templates correctly: app1/templates/app1/base.html instead of app1/templates/base.html

Answer (score 0):

@wfh18 resolved the problem.  Moving my templates to be a namespaced template, and updating the paths inside the templates accordingly resolved the problem.

From:

```
- djangoProject
  - djangoProject
  - app1
    - templates
      - index.html
      - base.html
      - topbar.html
      - footer.html
      - sidebar.html
  - user
    - templates
      - login.html
```

to:

```
- djangoProject
  - djangoProject
  - app1
    - templates
      - app1
        - index.html
        - base.html
        - topbar.html
        - footer.html
        - sidebar.html
  - user
    - templates
      - user
        - login.html
```

And changing any references to templates from `{% extends 'base.html' %}` to `{% extends 'app1/base.html' %}`, etc